# async.forEach is not accepting more than one parameter?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm using async.forEach to loop through an array and perform some tasks. One code snippet is as below.

```
var docs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], i = 0; 
async.forEach(docs, function(doc, async_callback_each){
    var _name = 'doc_each_' + (++i); 
    console.log(_name);
    async_callback_each(null, _name); 
    //Pass in no error and current function name, expecting to be printed. 
}, function(err, result) { 
    console.log('async_callback_each', err, result);    
})
```

Output of the code is

```
doc_each_1
doc_each_2
doc_each_3
doc_each_4
doc_each_5
async_callback_each undefined undefined
```

I'm happy that all array elements are processed before the callback is called, but note that I'm not able to receive _name passed in. It ends up as undefined. Is this normal or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: I guess you need to use async.map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Applies the function iterator to each item in arr, in parallel. The iterator is called with an item from the list, and a callback for when it has finished. If the iterator passes an error to its callback, the main callback (for the each function) is immediately called with the error.

Note, that since this function applies iterator to each item in parallel, there is no guarantee that the iterator functions will complete in order.

Arguments

arr - An array to iterate over.
iterator(item, callback) - A function to apply to each item in arr. The iterator is passed a callback(err) which must be called once it has completed. If no error has occurred, the callback should be run without arguments or with an explicit null argument.
callback(err) - A callback which is called when all iterator functions have finished, or an error occurs.
```